# php values are not printing

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to complete a task. for which i need to print `$message`(specified below). But its not printing i don't know what seems to be the problem. i thanks for your help in advance... and i don't wanna do this echo $message thing in the html code..and one thing you should know that the values are printing before echo `$message`. the php variables have values in them before the echo `$message`, but these same variables print nothing when i echo `$message`.. it only prints

Customer Name:

Customer Email:

Customer Mobile:

Customer City:

Customer Billing Address:

```
       <?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $bill_add=$_POST['message'];
   echo $message="
     <html><head> </head>

      <body>
       Customer Name: <?php echo  $name; ?>
       <br>
          Customer Email: <?php echo $email; ?>
        <br>
         Customer Mobile: <?php echo $mobile; ?>
       <br>
        Customer City: <?php echo $city; ?>
      <br>
    Customer Billing Address: <?php echo .$bill_add; ?>
    </body></html>";}
      ?>
```

HTML file:

```
   <html>
     <body>
           <form id="contact_form" action="#" method="POST"                    
          enctype="multipart/form-data" style="  padding-left: 121px;">

      <div class="row">
      <label for="name" style="  margin-left: 9px;">Your name:</label><br />
      <input id="name" class="input" name="name" type="text" value="" 
     size="30" required/><br />
       </div>
           </br>
           <div class="row">
      <label for="email" style="  margin-left: 9px;">Your email:</label><br    
      />
      <input id="email" class="input" name="email" type="text" value="" 
      size="30" required/><br />
     </div>
     </br>
     <div class="row">
    <label for="email" style="  margin-left: 9px;">Mobile #:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="mobile" type="text" value="" 
     size="30" required/><br />
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
    <label for="email" style="  margin-left: 9px;">City:</label><br />
    <input id="email" class="input" name="city" type="text" value="" 
    size="30" required/><br />
    </div>
    </br>
    <div class="row">
    <label for="message" style="  margin-left: 9px;">Shipping Address: 
     </label><br />
    <textarea id="message" class="input" name="message" rows="7" cols="32" 
     required></textarea><br />
     </div>
     </br>
     <div class="row">
     <input name="sub" id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Order Proceed 
      Now"  style="margin-top: 120px;background-color: green;padding:10px; 
     color:#FFF; "/>
     </div>
     </br>
    </form>                 
         </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Why is there a `<?php echo  $name; ?>` into a `<?php echo` ????

Comment: You got it wrong. First you set `$message`, then you `echo` it. Also, no need for reopening PHP tags, you **already** are in PHP code.

Comment: As D4V1D said, dont nest <?php ?>, dont assign and echo in same line (why would you??) plus i dont recall php letting you do multi-line without EOL syntax, though i may be mistaken on that (maybe just for certain use cases)

Comment: yeah thanks..the issue was the php tag..i just got confused... Thanks really:)

Comment: @DanielB: You *can* do multi-line `echo` without `EOL` syntax.

Comment: @D4V1D - sorry, yeh, i recall now i just had issues with nesting html and js so use <<<EOT for most cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your `$message` to :

```
 echo $message="
     <html><head> </head>

      <body>
       Customer Name: $name
       <br>
          Customer Email: $email
        <br>
         Customer Mobile: $mobile
       <br>
        Customer City: $city
      <br>
    Customer Billing Address: $bill_add
    </body></html>";}
      ?>
```

The problem was that you were using `<?php echo` into a `<?php echo`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['sub'])){

    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $mobile=$_POST['mobile'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $bill_add=$_POST['message'];
   echo "
     <html><head> </head>

      <body>
       Customer Name: ".$name."
       <br>
          Customer Email: ".$email."
        <br>
         Customer Mobile: ".$mobile."
       <br>
        Customer City: ".$city."
      <br>
    Customer Billing Address: ".$bill_add."
    </body></html>";}
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant use

so better use it like, Using concatenation in php solves your problem.

```
<?php 
    echo $message="
     <html><head> </head>

      <body>
       Customer Name: ".$name."
       <br>
          Customer Email: ".$email."
        <br>
         Customer Mobile: ".$mobile."
       <br>
        Customer City: ".$city."
      <br>
    Customer Billing Address: ".$bill_add."
    </body></html>";
      ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php   echo $message="<html><head> </head><body>Customer Name: " . $name . " <br>Customer Email: " . $email . " <br>Customer Mobile: " . $mobile . " <br>Customer City: " . $city . "<br>Customer Billing Address: " . $bill_add . " </body></html>";?>
```

// we are using concatenation here ( . ) so we don't need to write  and remove spaces.